# Nitgen Hamster DX HFDU06 and C# Dot Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

We are developing a multiplatform project in `C#` with `Dot Net Core` and we need to consume the `Nitgen Hamster DX HFDU06`.

For `Windows` we are using the `.dll` `NITGEN.SDK.NBioBSP`, but for `Linux` we did not find the `.so` file and documentation for development in `.Net Core`.
There is a `.so` file (`libNBioBSP.so`), but there is no documentation to consume the methods.

The `Nitgen` provides the `Java` `.tar` library, but I'm trying to avoid using `Java` in this context.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi Lucas, how did you do it in Windows, can you please give me a few pointers.

Comment: Hi Mudassir, in Windows we use the dll ( NITGEN.SDK.NBioBSP.dll ), import into the project ( add using NITGEN.SDK.NBioBSP ) and consume the methods:

public static readonly NBioAPI nbioapi = new NBioAPI ();

public static OutCompare CloseBiometry ()
{
 var iddevice = NBioAPI.Type.DEVICE_ID.AUTO;
 uint ResultClose = nbioapi.CloseDevice (iddevice);
 var resultmessage = new MessageError (). Error (ResultClose);
 resultmessage.IdDevice = iddevice;
 return resultmessage;
}

Comment: Thanks Lucas, will try this way.

Comment: Hi @Lucas Although the above C# code works, would you know, how does the Nitgen SDK connect to Access Manager (from Nitgen) to authenticate a user and get the Uname/Password from Access Manager?

Comment: @manishKungwani, are you asking about the compare method?

Comment: @Lucas Nitgen has another product Access Manager .. wondering if the FP compare or Verify works with the FPs stored in AM..